# Custom citing style

Tags: biblatex, citing, natbib

I am new to Latex, so I am sorry if I do not know something. I am writing here because I need to create my own citing style.

I have been doing research for the past 2 days, however, the further I go, the less I know. I found that there are similar citing styles to what I need (authoryear), but not exactly the same, but I do not know how to change one. I have tried to use biblatex, but unsuccessfully. The style I need should look like this:

1. In the text - (Author1 and Author2, 2016).
2. Actual journal reference - Author1, N. and Author2, N. (2016) The title. *Journal title*. Volume (Part), page numbers.

Page numbers are written as: pp. 62-65. Italics, capitalization and punctuation are very important.

I would be grateful if you could suggest me which method is the easiest to achieve this type of style. In addition, it would be great if you could direct me to a tutorial or something similar for creating custom styles.

EDIT:
I found that the apalike style from the natbib package produce a very close result to what I need. Nevertheless, following has to be changed:

1. Remove full stop after the date.
2. Have a full stop after the journal name (instead of a comma).
3. Instead of a colon after the issue number have a comma followed by pp.

All in all, the result should look like this:

[image: Outcome]

Please let me know what steps I should take to achieve this.

EDIT 2:

I have used the apa style from the biblatex because it looks similar to what I want to achieve. Current MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage[maxcitenames=3, style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}

%Truncate number of authors to 3
\makeatletter
\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
    \ifthenelse{\value{uniquelist}>1}
    {\numdef\cbx@min{\value{uniquelist}}}
    {\numdef\cbx@min{\value{minnames}}}%
    \ifboolexpr{test {\ifnumcomp{\value{listcount}}{=}{1}}
        or test {\ifnumcomp{\value{listtotal}}{=}{3}}} 
    {\usebibmacro{labelname:doname}%
        {\namepartfamily}%
        {\namepartfamilyi}%
        {\namepartgiven}%
        {\namepartgiveni}%
        {\namepartprefix}%
        {\namepartprefixi}%
        {\namepartsuffix}%
        {\namepartsuffixi}}
    {\ifnumcomp{\value{listcount}}{<}{\cbx@min + 1}% normal name
        {\usebibmacro{labelname:doname}%
        {\namepartfamily}%
        {\namepartfamilyi}%
        {\namepartgiven}%
        {\namepartgiveni}%
        {\namepartprefix}%
        {\namepartprefixi}%
        {\namepartsuffix}%
        {\namepartsuffixi}} 
        {}%
        \ifnumcomp{\value{listcount}}{=}{\cbx@min + 1}% first past ul is et al
        {\ifnumcomp{\value{listcount}}{<}{\value{listtotal}}
            {\andothersdelim\bibstring{andothers}}
            {\usebibmacro{labelname:doname}%
                {\namepartfamily}%
                {\namepartfamilyi}%
                {\namepartgiven}%
                {\namepartgiveni}%
                {\namepartprefix}%
                {\namepartprefixi}%
                {\namepartsuffix}%
                {\namepartsuffixi}}}%
        {}%
        \ifnumcomp{\value{listcount}}{>}{\cbx@min + 1}% nothing thereafter
        {\relax}%
        {}%
    }%
}
\makeatother

%Remove unnecessary information
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{doi}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{url}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{arxivId}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{arXiv}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{archivePrefix}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{eprint}}

%Replace & with 'and' in bibliography
\AtBeginBibliography{\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
        \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}>\maxprtauth}
        {}
        {\ifthenelse{\value{liststop}>2}
            {\finalandcomma\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}
            {\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}}}}

%Replace & with 'and' in citing
\AtEveryCitekey{\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
        \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}>\maxprtauth}
        {}
        {\ifthenelse{\value{liststop}>2}
            {\finalandcomma\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}
            {\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}}}}

%Remove full-stop after the date
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addspace}

%External database of citations
\addbibresource{library.bib}

\begin{document}
    \section{Test}
        \parencite{Blasco2002}, \parencite{Clarke2014},  \parencite{Blasco2002}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Outcome:

[image: Current outcome]

I am still having a few problems:

1. I have to change comma into a full stop after the Journal Title.
2. I have to add (pp. ) before the page numbers.

I found that people want to remove them, but how does one add them?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! The simplest way is to use `biblatex` and patch an existing style, as close as possible to what you want. It's not very hard, as biblatex uses a tex-like syntax, with the `xpatch` package, which has specific tools for `biblatex`. Could you post some code and explain  what you want to change?

Comment: @Bernard I would, but I don't know which code I want to change either. I followed one of the answers on SX, talking about creating a new *.bbx file, but I was lost there, too. I haven't found a method that most of the people use that I could follow as well. I posted the output I would like to receive, hoping that people will direct me towards the right path - e.g. info online, any method that is worth looking etc. Overall, I am not sure what to look for to achieve what I have described above.

Comment: The author-year style  yields more or less what you're asking for for references. For citations, if I understand well, you only want  the author(s) last name(s). You mention you tried biblatex unsuccessfully. Could you explain more in detail?

Comment: @Bernard I have uploaded more info about my problem. Is it possible to achieve what I need by using the natbib package?

Comment: Actually, I don't know very well  `natbib`, and I'm not used to customise `.bst`. I think I would be able to obtain what you want with `biblatex`.

Comment: If you posted the code you tried with Biblatex, it would be much easier to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addperiod\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}}%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addspace}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{issuename}%
  \newunit}
```

you will get a full stop after the journal title instead of the comma.

You can get the page numbers back with

```
\DeclareFieldFormat*{pages}{\mkpageprefix[bookpagination]{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{pagetotal}{\mkpagetotal[bookpagination]{#1}}
```